# How do I get a code to generate 4 different random numbers from 1 through 56?

Tags: java

This is a followup to my previous question. Using this code, I'd like to know how to generate 4 different random numbers from 1-56 for the yes case, same from 1-51 for the no case, and a loop back to the start for if neither case is used.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandomPerkSelector {

public static void main(String [] args){
Scanner userInputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Are you playing as a survivor?");
while(true){
String userInput = userInputReader.nextLine();
if(userInput.equals("Yes")){
   //"Yes" case
   //generate your numbers for "Yes"
   break;
}else if(userInput.equals("No")){
   //"No" case
   //generate your numbers for "No"
   break;
}else{
   System.out.println("This is a yes or no question.");
   continue; 
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: `I'm not sure if this code will loop yet or not with an answer outside of the "yes" or "no" boundaries.` -  Don't guess if it works. test the code!!! I'm sure you can run your code ant type yes/no/maybe just like any of us can.

Comment: The problem is that I honestly have no idea how to do the random number generation and have tried to find an answer and failed.

Comment: Okay, so if I can still put in input after I put in an answer different from "yes" or "no", is that considered it looping? Sorry, I'm actually quite new to java.

Comment: You tell me. Only you know what the requirement is. Does it do what YOU want? I would expect if the person enters an invalid value you would display a message and then prompt for the input again.

Comment: Well, it lets me still put in the input, so I guess?

Comment: *"4 **different** random numbers"* So {21,30,15,47} is OK but {21,30,15,30} is not (one number is repeated in 2nd set)?

Comment: Yeah, like that. In the game I want to use this for, the perks can be labeled as numbers, and you can't use 2 of the same perk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what your asking but this should make 4 random numbers up to 56.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int[] nums = new int[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int[i] = rand.nextint(57);
}
```

Comment: When you post code you should then 1) select the code you posted 2) click on the "{}" button so the code will retain its formatting. Also this code won't work, since you have a return statement when you do the first iteration of the loop. If you want 4 number you would add them to an Array or List.

Comment: (1+) for a simple loop.

Comment: When I input this code, it tells me that it's missing ] and ; on the 4th line even though it looks right, so I can't test it.

Comment: @SolFox. so fix the problem. Take the time to understand the suggestion. The OP made a typo.  The code you find here is not tested and is used to give you an example. You need to specify the variable name.

Comment: Okay, so by specify that you meant to put something in such as
    
    int PerkNumber;

right?

Comment: `put something in such as int PerkNumber; right?` - no. I meant if you look at the code you will see the int array variable name is "nums", so if you want to update the array you need to use the "nums" variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to avoid duplicating code.

```
    private static int obtainRandomNumberInRange(int min, int max) {
        if (min >= max) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Min in greater than Max value");
        }

        Random r = new Random();
        return r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    }
```

This, will return a int value between min and max. You can take this method and call it the times you want.

For example, 
If you are generating numbers for yes:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//This will call the function 4 times, and get numbers between 100 and 200. 
IntStream.range(0, 4).forEach(x-> numbers.add(obtainRandomNumberInRange(100, 200)));
```

Now the numbers have 4 random numbers between 100 and 200.

Or you can use a for statement:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
       numbers.add(obtainRandomNumberInRange(100, 200));
}
```

Comment: Seriously? the OP doesn't understand the basics of using if statements and a while loop and you are trying to solve the problem with a stream. Am I the only person who thinks people should learn the basics first before moving on to more advance features of the language?

Comment: @camickr *"Am I the only person who thinks people should learn the basics.."* Nope. I SMH at the Swing (about the only tag I explicitly follow these days) questions where the OP does not understand simple if / else statements or looping structures, or solving (or at least investigating) basic compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

i do not know what you are going to do but you can use this code

```
int n = 2 * (Integer.MAX_VALUE / 3);
int low = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
if (random(n) < n/2) {
    low++;
 System.out.println(low);
 }
```

by this method you will never get repeated number 
i hope you will understand.